# "App blocked" message in Google Sheets for "AdWords Data Grabber by Optmyzr"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-script

I have tried using this Google Ads Script along with a Google Sheets Template found in this article: https://searchengineland.com/script-automates-adding-adwords-data-google-spreadsheet-277724

Link to my Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XyF8V4Xhi7MLNwDWGsHV3a10M-g9HiAD0sWGLh9wfak/edit?usp=sharing

Google Sheets: When I click;
AdWords Data Grabber from Optmyzr - Choose Report Type - Selecting any report
I have to approve the app. But then I get an error saying;

> **This app is blocked**
>
> This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

It also seems like the onOpen function fail

[image: onOpen function fail]

Answer (score 0):

If the app doesn't meet Google's [security standards](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255#more-secure-apps-how), Google may block access to your account through them by default. Less secure apps can make it easier for hackers to access your account, so blocking sign-in from these apps helps keep your account secure.

You can try to bypass it via:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps, but understand that you are putting yourself at risk.

[Source](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/111344249?hl=en&msgid=111523989)